# Shell script: the child process do not terminate in linux

Tags: shell-scripting, multiprocessing

I have written a shell script to initiate three background process in the same time. In shell script I am trying to wait for all children to finish their job and then the parent job to terminate. But, with some reason I see the the sleeping processes never awakes.

```
echo "Starting $1 instances" >> $logfile
for i in `seq 1 $1`
do
        /usr/bin/php index.php name&
done

echo "Waiting for all $l instances to complete \n" >> $logfile
wait
echo "All $instances scripts completed"  >>  $logfile
```

Comment: While @StevenMonday's answer is the right way to do it, I'd like to point out the "-C" argument to ps.  Rather than "ps|grep|grep", you can just do `ps -C myscript.sh` to find all the processes with that name.

Comment: The child processes will always appear in `ps` as zombies because their parent (your script) is spending all its time polling and cannot handle their exit.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `bash`, you should use the `wait` command, rather than an elaborate polling loop. I don't know about other shells (sh, zsh, and so on), but I assume most/all of them also have `wait`, or an equivalent to it.

Comment: Running just `wait` is the right way to do this. :)  POSIX defines the wait utility for use by a POSIX-compliant shell, so it should be there on any shell that matters. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wait.html

Comment: I have updated my script to use wait but now I get "wait: pid 17577 is not a child of this shell".....whats wrong ?

Comment: @user269867: Since I wrote my answer, you have edited your question to replace `sleep` with `wait` inside your polling loop. I will repeat my advice, but more clearly this time: Remove the polling loop. As @dannysauer commented, you should just `wait`. `wait` without any arguments will wait for all child processes, so you don't need to save child process PIDs.

Comment: My intention from this script is to initiate multiple process and then wait to their completion. I have a cron entry with it which is which call this script every min with "2" ..I am confused if I am doing it all right...

Comment: @StevenMonday I have edited my script can you please check if it's right?. I have a question - the wait without argument will wait till parent is not finished? How can I retrieve my script process id in the script?